# R : how to define date and time format

Tags: r, datetime

I have a following time stamps.

> outlist
>   "19980202_0810" "19980202_0815" "19980202_0820"

I want to have 
"1998-02-02T08:10:00Z" "1998-02-02T08:15:00Z" "1998-02-02T08:20:00Z"

All I can do either "1998-02-02 08:10:00 PST".

> time_obj = strptime(outlist, format = "%Y%m%d_%H%M")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strptime` is the import function; `strftime` is the format (output) function although I think most people would just use `format`:

```
outlist <- c("19980202_0810", "19980202_0815", "19980202_0820")
time_obj=strptime(outlist, format = "%Y%m%d_%H%M") 
format( time_obj , format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
#[1] "1998-02-02T08:10:00Z" "1998-02-02T08:15:00Z" "1998-02-02T08:20:00Z"
```

At the moment these are POSIXlt items:

```
> class(time_obj)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

It would be safer to convert to POSIXct:

```
> time_obj=as.POSIXct(outlist, format = "%Y%m%d_%H%M")
> time_obj
[1] "1998-02-02 08:10:00 PST" "1998-02-02 08:15:00 PST" "1998-02-02 08:20:00 PST"
> class(time_obj)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

POSIXlt objects are not handled well in data.frames.

Edit: The `print` method for POSIXct objects is documented in `?DateTimeClasses` and the help page for `format.POSIXct` is at``srtftime` which I already cited:

```
strftime(time_obj, tz = "UTC")
[1] "1998-02-02 16:10:00" "1998-02-02 16:15:00" "1998-02-02 16:20:00"
```

Comment: You can put in pretty much any letter or punctuation as long as it's not preceded by a percent-sign. Internally the POSIXct objects are numeric and are all GMT/UCT, but when output to the console they will respect your timezone. (It can be fairly maddening trying to keep that straight.)

Comment: It does. How can I keep GMT/UCT?